# Change block location on page by page basis?

Tags: 7, blocks

I am working on a custom theme that's inheriting defaults from Bartik. I want to specify that the 'recent content' block should appear in the content area on the homepage, but the left sidebar on article pages.

I see how to specify a specific area for the block on a specific page, but no way to set a different area on a different page or duplicate the block. I'm thinking it might be most logical to duplicate it, so I have front-page recent content and regular recent content, since they might look a little different. But not sure how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming 'recent content' is "just" the output of a view, so, if I that is correct, you can create any numbers of blocks with that content by just going into views and clone()ing the display and thus creating another block that could then be placed wherever you want.

Comment: it's just one of the blocks available in the list of blocks.. I'm actually not sure where it's coming from other than that, I think it's just there by default but I don't see any corresponding View under Views...

Comment: I recommend ignoring the recent content liste d in blocks and go with Jimajamma's recommendation to create your own view.  That will give you greater control of the output format and theming as well as allowing two blocks on a page defined for different content types..

Comment: this 'recent content' thing is not under views (i don't have anything not greyed out under views except for a slideshow plugin i used) so no idea how to clone it..

Comment: my point is that you can create a view, filter it on node types you are interested in, sort it by post date, and format it to your site's specific heart's content, no pun, and then create as many blocks from that as you want.