# How to change the position of a block in a particular page?

Tags: 7, blocks

I have a Drupal's default `User Login` block in `Side bar first` region at the last position. Reference page: http://indiansnakes.org/snakes

The proposed home page has been redesigned and the `User Login` block has to be displayed in the `Footer Fourth` region. Reference Page: http://indiansnakes.org/homepage

So, the `User Login` block should appear in footer fourth only for this new homepage but for the rest of the pages in websites it has to continue to stay in the `Side bar first` region. In normal scenarios if it was a custom block, then I can create a clone of the same block and change the visibility per page / set of pages. But `User Login` block is system defined and it does not allow me to clone or duplicate it.

I tried searching if someone has already addressed this issue but it seems like not. Looking forward for thoughts.

Edit:
Nearest I could find is this: [Change block location on page by page basis?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/17239/change-block-location-on-page-by-page-basis). But the solution there was to create multiple blocks from same view, unfortunately `User Login` is not based out of views for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can place the default `User Login` block in Sidebar first region at the last position. You can exclude this block from being shown in Homepage using 'Visibility settings' which is available in the block edit page.

[image]

Then you can use front page template `page--front.tpl.php` and render the block manually by passing the block markup through `hook_preprocess_page()`.

```
function THEME_NAME_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
  $front_page = drupal_is_front_page();
  if ($front_page) {
    $user_login= block_load('user', 'login');
    $vars['user_login'] = _block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($user_login)));
  }
}
```

Then you should print the `$user_login` variable in the front page template inside the `Footer Fourth` region.

Comment: Awesome answer! Will try this in the evening and accept it if it works for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

the context module does this (and more):
https://www.drupal.org/project/context

it lets you make a context based on page (so front), then you tell it to display a block where you want it.

you can then make a second context based on page (not front) and display it in the other region.

this lets you reuse the block and avoids writing custom php in your template file.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for bringing it out. I will explore it.